# How can I make a css class that is a modification of another?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I'm using google's MDL for a simple website I'm making.  I have a lot of buttons on the website, on a few various pages, that I would like to all have the same look at feel.  The starting point is to include a few MDL styles to the buttons, like so:

```
<button class="mdl-button" style="..."/>
```

This is great, but I want to add some additional features to the buttons over the default mdl style.  I want to do something like:

```
.my_button_style {
    ... include mld-button style
    ... include mdl-xxx style
    ... other css parameters here
}
```

I've done some digging, but it appears that there is no way to inherit properties from other css classes when creating a new one, using standard CSS (without using something like LESS).

*This seems insane to me.*

I see a lot of examples on the MDL website such as:

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored">
  <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

If you want all your buttons to look like that, do you really have to add each and every one of the styles to every button instance across your whole site?  Why are CSS developers not marching down to Mountain View with pitchforks and torches?  Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: AFAIK MDL is **not** a google thing. Anyway, having orthogonal classes which are all applied to an element is a Good Thing, and a standard CSS best practice. Among other things, it makes the HTML more readable, because one can see at a glance what styles are being applied.

Comment: Actually, I believe it is.  Here is a post from Addy Osmani (engineer on the Chrome team) introducing MDL, using the phrase "Today we are releasing our effort to bring this to websites using vanilla CSS, HTML and JavaScript. We’re calling it Material Design Lite (MDL).": https://medium.com/google-developers/introducing-material-design-lite-3ce67098c031

Comment: And I'm not persuaded by your argument of readability.  A jumble of "mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--colored" is much less readable than simply having one clear, custom name.  Classes are already obscuring what styles are specifically applied, and rely on good naming practices to be readable.  Furthermore, any time you want to change the style of a button across your whole site, you have to FIND AND REPLACE across all the html on your site.

Comment: You haven't explained what issues you have with "something like LESS", because it seems to me that's the perfect solution to your problem.

Comment: AFAIK, only using preprocessors, can you include content like that.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, using LESS adds a cumbersome step to my process that is probably more annoying than having to find-and-replace.  If somebody knows for a fact that it is not possible without pre-processors,  then I guess I would accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It appears that there is no way to inherit properties from other CSS classes when creating a new one, using standard CSS

That is correct.

It's hard to prove that a feature does not exist, but you will search in vain for any such feature in any CSS spec.

Since you appear to be resistant to any notion of a design philosophy involve orthogonal classes which are combined at the HTML level, I will not spend any additional time trying to motivate that approach, or justifying the "omission" of extending classes from the CSS spec.

Meanwhile you might take a look at https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-extend-rule/, but this is not part of any existing or proposed spec that I am aware of. In any case, the existence of this proposal in itself may be taken as "proof" that `@extends` is not already part of CSS anywhere.

Although personally I cannot recommend using SASS, there are other preprocessor frameworks that provide `extends` in a less intrusive way. If your app already uses any kind of build process, adding such as preprocessing step should not be "cumbersome" at all, and is likely to involve nothing more than adding a couple of lines to some config file. For instance, you could look at https://github.com/travco/postcss-extend.

Comment: I think that rigorous proof is rarely a requirement for stackoverflow questions, and certainly not in this case.